# Could the "shift triggering opportunity actions" thread be closed, for re-build?

Tags: discussion

This is a bit of a strange case.  I have a question which I would like closed, so that it can be re-built into its proper forms.

[Does shifting count as movement, for the purpose of triggering non-attack opportunity actions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5819/197)

The situation with this is that the thread has become horribly mangled from its original intent, and also quite confusing to a degree.  I would rather it be taken out and replaced by the three separate questions which are actually discussed in the one thread:

`1. Does shifting count as movement, for the purpose of triggering non-attack opportunity actions?`

- This is of course, the title of the existing question.  I still feel this particular question will be of value to the community.

`2. Can immediate actions be triggered by shifting?`

- This, as it turns out, is the actual question I was looking to have answered.  The power referenced is an immediate action, not an opportunity action.

`3. Can Pursuit of the Hunter be used to move away from the triggering enemy?`

- This is a question totally unrelated, except in that it refers to the same power I've given as an example in my question.  However, it has been raised (and in some cases become the primary feature) in some answers to my question.

Could a diamond mod take out this question, or advise what other corrective action should be taken?  I don't want to post the replacements until the original is dealt with, to avoid close-as-duplicate votes.

EDIT - Took Pat's advice and made the new threads.  Voting to close the original as an exact duplicate of the first of these:

[Can shifting trigger immediate actions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6024/does-shifting-trigger-immediate-actions)
[Can shifting trigger non-attack opportunity actions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/can-shifting-trigger-non-attack-opportunity-actions)
[Can Pursuit of the Hunter be used to move away from the triggering enemy?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6025/can-pursuit-of-the-hunter-be-used-to-move-away-from-the-triggering-enemy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should post your new questions, and then we can dup the old one to one of the new ones.

Comment: Ah.  I didn't think of reversing it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can mod close it but am remote and doing it via iPhone - please post the new question links in a comment on that q and then I'll close.

Comment: I have added the links as a comment.

Comment: I have closed the original.